# How to Convert String to JSONArray in java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert `String` to `JSONArray` but i am getting

```java
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"name":"mobilenumber","value":"9010000000"},{"name":"amount","value":"200"},{"name":"ccffee","value":"0"},{"name":"totalfee","value":"200"}] of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Code:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/getpayment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String getbillpayment(@RequestBody String req) {
    System.out.println("Request...." + req);
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(req);
    System.out.println(array.length());
    return "";
}
```

My input Request String:

```
[{\"name\":\"mobilenumber\",\"value\":\"9010000000\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"value\":\"200\"},{\"name\":\"ccffee\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"name\":\"totalfee\",\"value\":\"200\"}]
```

Comment: It works for me, maybe your `req` is escaped by the framework you are using?

Comment: try using `"[{\"name\":\"mobilenumber\",\"value\":\"9010000000\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"value\":\"200\"},{\"name\":\"ccffee\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"name\":\"totalfee\",\"value\":\"200\"}]"`

Comment: @dkb: i tried your answer but getting same issue.

Comment: @michalk: Spring Boot and thymeleaf

Comment: Another **works for me**

Comment: @Deadpool: printing logs liks `Request....[{\"name\":\"mobilenumber\",\"value\":\"9010000000\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"value\":\"200\"},{\"name\":\"ccffee\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"name\":\"totalfee\",\"value\":\"200\"}]`

Comment: @Durga your log should not contain \ with your input

Comment: @Azarea: Sir check my Updated input

Comment: @Durga try unescaping your String - `req = req.replace("\\", "");` - it should work, however you should investigate why Jackson escapes your request and maybe consider using POJOs instead of plain String in your constoller method.

Comment: @michalk: i tried your suggestion but getting like `org.json.JSONException: Value [{ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two libraries containing the similar `JSONArray` class which makes it confusing somehow:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

The `org.json` library has a `JSONArray` class which has a constructor accepting a `String` that can be parsed to a `JSONArray`. This is working when you have some simple form of Json array string like this:

> ["One", "two"]

So you can parse it simply like this to achieve the `JSONArray`:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String val = "[\"One\", \"Two\"]";

        JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray(val);  
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println( jsonArr.getString( i ) );
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work simply for more complex Json strings similar to yours which is containing Json objects with multiple properties.

In this case you may find the other library more helpful. It has a `JSONParser` class that can parse complex Json objects within the strings:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

public class JSONArrayTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String val = "[{\"name\":\"mobilenumber\",\"value\":\"9010000000\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"value\":\"200\"},{\"name\":\"ccffee\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"name\":\"totalfee\",\"value\":\"200\"}]";

        JSONArray jsonArr = (JSONArray) new JSONParser().parse( val );

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) jsonArr.get( i );
            System.out.println( jsonObj );
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
    JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
    org.json.simple.JSONObject jobj=(org.json.simple.JSONObject)parse.parse(your String);

Iterator obj = jobj.keys();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

while (obj.hasNext()){
    String key = (String) obj.next();
    jsonArray.put(obj.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
    String value = "[{\"name\":\"mobilenumber\",\"value\":\"9010000000\"},{\"name\":\"amount\",\"value\":\"200\"},{\"name\":\"ccffee\",\"value\":\"0\"},{\"name\":\"totalfee\",\"value\":\"200\"}]";

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    jsonArray.add(value);

    System.out.println(jsonArray);
```

Hopefully this will help, Happy coding

Comment: There is no such method as jsonArray.add